# N in M : random choice

Tags: pdftex, random-numbers

What is the most simple way, in pdflatex, to have a command such that `\NinM{n}{m}{c}{d}` will expand to `c` with probability n/m and will expand to `d` with probability 1-n/m ?

Comment: The question isn't really clear. It's probably easy to define a macro that does this, but it's not obvious what the end result should be.

Comment: Though our high-rep user base consists of mainly mathematicians, please note that this is not a TeX question per se if you don't give the relevant background for the distribution and its probable use case with a ME (minimal example) .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pdftex` has a `\pdfuniformdeviate` primitive that expands to a random integer between `0` and its argument.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\NinM#1#2#3#4{%
  \ifnum\numexpr\pdfuniformdeviate #2-1\relax<#1\relax
    #3%
  \else
    #4%
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\NinM{2}{10}{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be N in M+1, but it's ok !

Comment: +1 Good solution, which doesn't require any package. I think it should be `\ifnum\numexpr\pdfuniformdeviate #2-1\relax<#1\relax`, though: there are n integers between 0 and n-1 (inclusive), and m-n integers between n and m-1 (inclusive); therefore, you have a probability of n/m that the random integer generated be strictly smaller than n, and a probability of (m-n)/m=1-n/m that it be greater or equal to n. Also, you should remove spurious spaces by adding `%` after `#3` and `#4`.

Comment: No :) I should be thanking you, because I didn't know of `\pdfuniformdeviate` before seeing your answer.

Comment: @Jubobs `pdftex` introduces a lot of primitives that are very interesting and that simplify the job at a macro level. Thanks to Heiko Oberdiek, there is also a `pdftexcmds` package that makes them (not all) available in `luatex`.

Comment: @cjorssen What is a good source for learning about those commands?

Comment: @Jubobs [`texdoc pdftex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf) and [`texdoc pdftexcmds`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.pdf).